# How to pass values from selected checkboxes

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller

```
This is my view, in this code I select all checkboxes but when I reload my values are not saved, bcs i can't pass nothing in to the controller.

<table class="table table-striped grid-table">
<tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Code</th>
    <th>
    <input type="checkbox" id="box"/>
    </th>
</tr>
@foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<cit.Models.getPersonPerName_Result>)Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.idper</td>
        <td>@item.pername</td>
        <td>      

         <div class="pure-checkbox">
           <input type="checkbox" id="@item.idper" class="chk" checked="@(item.idperson == ViewBag.idperson ? true : false)" name="@item.id.ToString()" id="@item.id.ToString()" />
           <label for="@item.id.ToString()"></label>
         </div>

        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Here is my js

```
    var selectAllBox = document.getElementById('box');
    selectAllBox.addEventListener('click', function () {
        var pureCheckboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('chk');

        for (var i = 0; i < pureCheckboxes.length; i++) {
            pureCheckboxes[i].checked = this.checked;
        }
    });
```

My boxes need to be checked on the next reload, in this code I have about 10 persons who can access to  this web app

> checked="@(item.idperson == ViewBag.idperson ? true : false)"

Answer (score 0):

Your inputs need to be inside a form and you need a post method that accepts the form inputs as parameters when the form is submitted.  Alternatively, you can post the values using Ajax. You'll need some sort of persistence like a database to store the values so they can be loaded on next reload without submitting the form.

You shouldn't need to cast your model to anything to iterate through it. You should just pass something like

```
var model = new List<cit.Models.getPersonPerName_Result>() {
    //Populate here
}
return View(model);
```